# How to enable mouse hover on subtitle or title of pie chart using highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

My requirement is to show a div containing the colors of each pie slice on mouse hover on the subtitle of the pie chart. I am using highchart.js. How to acheive this. Please help.

[Please find the attached image for mor information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS3R2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach  mouseenter event on subtitle/title. You can do it on load event. Then you should create a div which contains all information and styles.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const menu = document.createElement('div');
        menu.style.cssText = 'left:' + (this.plotLeft + this.plotWidth * 0.5) + 'px; top:' + (this.plotTop + this.plotHeight * 0.1) + 'px; position: absolute; display: none; background-color:white; padding: 20px';

        let str = '';

        this.series[0].data.forEach(point => {
          str += '<p><div style="display:inline-block;padding-right: 10px;width:10px;height:10px;background-color:' + point.color + ';background-clip:content-box;"></div>' + point.name + '</p>'
        });

        str += '';
        menu.innerHTML = str;
        this.renderTo.appendChild(menu);

        this.subtitle.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
          menu.style.display = 'block';
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/farucbbu/

Comment: Thank You this is what i wanted. But i am unable to get the value for this.series[0].data.forEach(point => {,.... this.series[0] is giving me undefined when i checked in console. what could be the problem.

Comment: Did you load any series to the chart? Check what this refers to inside the callback.

Comment: Please find my code in the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/j43sr6hk/1/ and kindly suggest me where i am going wrong. I am loading series dynamically by using chart.addSeries({...}) method.

Comment: You should make the menu code after you add series - before that you do not have any series and this is why the code does not work. So do it in your ajax success callback after the series is added.

Comment: Hats off to you . A big big big Thank You. Its worked for me only i need to change the this object to my chart object. Thank You very much.

Comment: On more help required.. If i select any porion of the pie chart the all pie chart covered with the selected slice with the same color how to achieve this.I am not using drill down.js.. currently it is getting covered with blue color only whatever slice i choose.

Comment: If you have another question, create a new topic with all details - and do not forget to attach the code or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use **tooltip** option.

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 3
}
```

For more information go to 
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip

Comment: My requirement is to show the tool tip on mouse hover on the "View All Label" that is subtitle in the attached image